# Get all meta boxes values

Tags: metabox

I want to list all the values of a custom metabox in a custom post type.

Here is the code to get the one meta box in a single post

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'institution_location', true);?>
```

but say I want to list all the meta boxes in the home page or a dropdown menu in a search form not just in a single page

the metabox code

```
 add_meta_box(
    'Location_metabox',
    __( 'Location ', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'institution_location_metabox_output',
    'institution',
    'side'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use WP_Query and it works fine.

```
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'institution');
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->next_post();
    $id= $the_query->post->ID;
    $location = get_post_meta($id, 'institution_location', true);
    echo $location;
    endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [get_post_custom](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom), that will return an array of all meta values linked to the post

Comment: Thanks hannit I tried WP_Query and it works for me, updated solutions. I think get_post_custom will work for a single post.

Comment: you are right of course